# Wireless serial programming without the need to press a button to program it

Tags: arduino, uart, bluetooth, programming, atmega328p

After a long play, I made this adapter to be able to program a Pro Mini wireless via BlueTooth. The long play wasn't the adapter but the settings of the BlueTooth module (baudrate is fixed and need to be changed to firmware upload speed).

[image: SPP-Programmer]

It is working great however I need to press reset every time I want to update the firmware on the Pro Mini. That is a little pointless to be wireless, it would be great without the need to press reset every time I need to update the software.

The STATE to DTR seems to be doing nothing, get this from examples however doesn't do anything. Most of the examples use the HC-05 but I am using a SPP-C module (a different 'beast'), to be exactly, a JDY-30-V2.6, Bluetooth V3.0 .

The STATE pin (BlueTooh module) is to indicate a connection is established (HIGH) and when connection is refused (LOW). That is not very useful and the opposite the DTR pin requires (and is too slow).

What can I do to automate the programming feature? I have tried several things, connecting the STATE to the RESET pin, mess around with some resistors however doesn't work out to a solution.

Any directions or ideas what to do or is what I want impossible with this configuration?

---

Some datasheets

- [JDY-30](http://www.ko4bb.com/getsimple/data/uploads/jdy-30/jdy-30-bluetooth-module.pdf)
- [ATMega328p](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf)

Comment: What software are you using to program the Pro Mini?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Don't think it make any sense to know (because it is a hardware thing) but I use Arduino IDE,  Sloeber and AVR-dude.

Comment: You could use software to latch a reset pulse to the board? It seems strange you only need to drive a reset and not a boot pin too. The software way would be: open the serial connection, send a special sequence to latch a reset, the open a new connection to upgrade the firmware.